# How do I successfully use Xamarin Forms Share Extension to share NSUserDefaults value?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, nsuserdefaults, ios8-share-extension

I'm trying to implement a **Xamarin Forms Share Extension** to allow my app to receive a zip file from another app.

I have successfully set up the **App Group** in the Apple Developer Account, am successfully able to see a shared url for the file, but am now having problems trying to sync the file back to the Container app via **NSUserDefaults**.

Here is my code with logging statements to cater for the fact that Extension apps can't be debugged in Xamarin Forms (as far as I know):

```
internal class CodeBasedViewController : SLComposeServiceViewController
{
    public override async void DidSelectPost()
    {
        int count = 0;
        try
        {
            NSExtensionItem item = ExtensionContext.InputItems[0];

            foreach(NSItemProvider prov in item.Attachments)
            {
                Log(count++.ToString());
                if (prov.HasItemConformingTo(UTType.URL) == true)
                {
                    Log("url type ok");

                    //Load item with Load Completion action
                    prov.LoadItem(UTType.URL, null, async (dataRaw, error) =>
                    {
                        Log("load url item ok");

                        //dataRaw is "file:///Users/appname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/..GUID1../data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/...GUID2.../
                        string uri = dataRaw.ToString();
                        Log2(uri);

                        NSUserDefaults shared = new NSUserDefaults(
                                    "group.com.companyname.appname.ShareExtension",
                                     NSUserDefaultsType.SuiteName);

                        shared.SetString(uri, "zipfile");
                        if (shared.Synchronize())
                        {
                            //sync completes successfully and code comes here
                            Log("sync success");

                        }
                        else
                            Log("sync failed");
                            
                        
                        
                        //base.DidSelectPost();

                    });

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log("ex: " + e.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

I have several questions or problems:

1. The `LoadItem` Completion action takes about 7 secs to come through which seems like a long time for a 6kb file.
2. If I uncomment `base.DidSelectPost()` the Extension is dismissed almost immediately upon clicking **Post**, making me suspect my Completion action code is being bypassed.
3. When I look at `NSUserDefaults` upon my Container apps activation, the uri value hasn't come through. (I am guessing if I can get this uri value in my Container, I will finally have access to the zip file.)

```
public override void OnActivated(UIApplication uiApplication)
{
    base.OnActivated(uiApplication);

    NSUserDefaults shared = new NSUserDefaults(
                "group.com.companyname.appname.ShareExtension",
                 NSUserDefaultsType.SuiteName);

    //ok = true
    bool ok = shared.Synchronize();

    //this is null!!
    string uri = shared.StringForKey("zipfile");

}
```

Any ideas on what is going wrong here?

**UPDATE**

I've gone into my host VM and created two XCode apps which mirror the bundle names of my container and share extension apps on my Windows VS machine. The XCode apps also have AppGroups configured to them.

This still doesn't work. I'm not sure what else I can try. Any ideas?

**UPDATE 02**

I'm posting my **Info.plist** files here to provide more info.

Can anyone see if I'm doing something wrong here:

**Container App**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <integer>2</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>8.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>MyApp</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.companyname.MyApp</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>MyApp</string>
    <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
    <string>Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset</string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**SharedApp**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>MyApp ShareExtension</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>MyApp.iOS.ShareExtension</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.companyname.MyApp.ShareExtension</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>com.your-company.MyApp.iOS.ShareExtension</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>XPC!</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>8.0</string>
    <key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsMovieWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
        <string>CodeBasedViewController</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Did you check whether the `"group.com.companyname.appname.ShareExtension"` is same as the `<key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>` in the xcode or not?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Liyun. I'm currently running on Windows with XCode on a remote macOS VM. Do I mean I need to create the extension on XCode as well?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, what I mean you show check `"group.com.companyname.appname.ShareExtension"` is same as the `<key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>` in the info.plist in your forms and ios part.

Comment: You are partly right. I didn't have `NSExtensionPointIdentifier` set in my container app **info.plist**. I put it in there with the value of `com.apple.share-services`  (not the appgroup name which is set in the **Entitlements.plist**). Unfortunately this still doesn't help pass the `NSUserDefaults` value.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer.

In addition to the above settings I also need to add the **Entitlements.plist** to the respective container and extension projects. I thought that was done by default, simply by being a part of the project but I was wrong.

You also need to:

1. Go to project **Properties** -> **iOS Bundle Signing** -> **Custom Entitlements**
2. Browse for and select the **Entitlements.plist** file

Do this both for container and extension apps.

**NSUserDefaults** should then be visible in both container and extension apps!